# json picture - image fetching

Tags: android, json

is there anyway of fetching image from a json link in an android studio code.

We have a json link which contains all information about a product. the json link populates our array list so that items can be displayed. now we want to fetch image as well.. is there any possibility.

Comment: Not clear. Can you post the json of one item ?

Comment: @SimonPA here, this is my json  http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems

Comment: So your image link is not in the json ? you want to  fetch the image at the same time as the json ?